# Creating multiple proportion table in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr, proportions

I've the following table

| Result_Group | Review |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 4 |
| A | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 5 |
| D | 4 |
| E | 5 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| E | 2 |

```
df = structure(list(Result_Group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
              ), class = "factor"), Review = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L)), 
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Does anyone know how can create a table for the proportion of the review for each group? Currently I'm doing it group by group and it's taking quite a while just to subset the data.

i.e. the table as follows:

| Review | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.67 | 0 | 0.67 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.33 | 0 | 0.33 | 0 | 0.50 |
| 3 | 0 | 0.50 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0.50 | 0 | 0.5 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.5 | 0.50 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  group_by(Result_Group) |> 
  count(Review) |> 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(-n) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Result_Group,
              values_from = prop,
              values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 5 x 6
  Review     A     B     C     D     E
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      1 0.667   0   0.667   0     0  
2      2 0.333   0   0.333   0     0.5
3      3 0       0.5 0       0     0  
4      4 0       0.5 0       0.5   0  
5      5 0       0   0       0.5   0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidy approach using dplyr and tidyr

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  # Add count values (all equal to 1)
  mutate(count = 1) %>% 
  
  # Pivot wider to get A, B, C.. as column names, and sum of count as values
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    id_cols = Review,
    names_from = Result_Group,
    values_from = count,
    values_fn = sum,
    values_fill = 0 # NAs are turned into 0
  ) %>% 
  
  # Mutate to get fractions instead of count
  mutate(
    across(
      -Review,
      ~ .x / sum(.x)
    )
  ) %>% 
  
  # Sort by review
  arrange(Review)


#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   Review     A     B     C     D     E
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      1 0.667   0   0.667   0     0  
#> 2      2 0.333   0   0.333   0     0.5
#> 3      3 0       0.5 0       0     0  
#> 4      4 0       0.5 0       0.5   0  
#> 5      5 0       0   0       0.5   0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>